# Caliburn Micro: DialogResult

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, dialogresult

I can't find a solution for the following problem:

I open a Dialog with the WindowManager from caliburn micro:

```
public void UserNew()
{
   this._windowManager.ShowDialog(new UserViewModel(this._windowManager));
}
```

Now I need a DialogResult when the user close the dialog with the OK button. The ShowDialog method of WindowManager don't return a DialogResult...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to use the View Model to handle determining what happened in the dialog. For instance, you can have an `IsCancelled` property on your `UserViewModel` that you can interrogate after returning from the `ShowDialog` call. Something like:

```
public void UserNew() {
    var userViewModel = new UserViewModel(this._windowManager);
    this._windowManager.ShowDialog(userViewModel);
    if (userViewModel.IsCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellation
    } else {
        // Handle other case(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer, where you only have to inherit from Screen and don't have to add a property yourself to the vm.

Answer (score 10):

In caliburn micro in your dialogviewmodel which inherits from **Screen** you can do:

```
TryClose(true); // for OK
```

or

```
TryClose(false); // for Cancel
```

then you could do:

```
var vm = IoC.Get<MyViewModel>();
var r = WindowManager.ShowDialog(vm, null, null);

if (r.HasValue && r.Value) {
  // do something on OK
}
```

your xaml of the dialog might look like this:

```
<Button Content="OK" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [AcceptButton()]" />
<Button Content="Cancel" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [CancelButton()]" />
```

using this namespace:

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

This is a detailed code sample of the dialog viewmodel implementation:

```
public bool CanAcceptButton
{
  get { return true; /* add logic here */ }
}

public void AcceptButton()
{
  TryClose(true);
}

public bool CanCancelButton
{
  get { return true; }
}

public void CancelButton()
{
  TryClose(false);
}
```

Comment: instead of "var r = WindowManager..." change that to "bool? r = WindowManager..."

because if you return TryClose(false) then Visual Studio 2010 makes it a boolean and crashes on the if (r.HasValue)  because a bool doesn't have .HasValue.

Answer (score 0):

WPF dialogs return nullable bools instead of DialogResults.  Caliburn's ShowDialog also returns `bool?`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx)

> Dialog boxes commonly allow users to accept or cancel the task for
>   which they were shown before the dialog box is closed. ShowDialog
>   returns a Nullable Boolean value that specifies whether the
>   activity was accepted or canceled. The return value is the value of
>   the DialogResult property before a window closes. For more
>   information, see DialogResult.

`DialogResult` above refers to the `bool` property called DialogResult on `System.Windows.Window`.

If you want to return something more complex just define your own enum property on your window and read its value once the dialog has closed.

Comment: How can I set the value of the nullable boolean? Currently I close the dialog with (GetView() as Window).Close() from the dialog view model.

Comment: I found also a solution to set the bool return value in the UserViewModel: var window = GetView() as Window; window.DialogResult = false; window.Close();