# Passing Message to a Static Class in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro for Implementing MVVM in WPF.

I have a static class named JIMSMessageBox,
there is also a ViewModel named MessageViewModel.

Actually these classes helps me insead of the normal MessageBox.

I used to call the JIMSMessageBox by

```
JIMSMessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
```

But, now i also want to implement an ConfirmBox in the same class JIMSMessage. But my problem is when i show the user a confirm box, he may accept or reject. so if the user clicks OK in the MessageWindow, i have to return true to JIMSMessage.Confirm, else if click Cancel, i have to return false.

How can i implement this using Caliburn Micro.

I need to have the JIMSMessage as a static class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something similar to my answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604692/263665.

You could pass a reference to your view model into your static method to help display a custom view for the "confirm" functionality and storing the state/result.